# Symfony2 and the MVC concept of view model

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns, symfony, naming-conventions

I think that Symfony2 is missing the concept of **ViewModel** (like ASP.NET MVC Framework), that is the model associated to a view. Symfony2 (as documentation) usually assign an **array** to a view.

A view model could be a PHP class but it's something different from the form model and sometimes it's the same as a domain entity. It' sometimes useful when dealing with a great amount of information to be displayed.

Anyway, is there any convention about where view models should go in Symfony2? Any specific folder? By now i have:

```
Symfony2/src/MyCompany/MyBundle/Form/Model
```

which holds models associated to forms. And:

```
Symfony2/src/MyCompany/MyBundle/Entity
```

for domain entities (bounded to database tables).

Suggestions are much appreciated. What about `Symfony2/src/MyCompany/MyBundle/Model`?

Comment: It's not mandatory to implement MVC to have a ViewModel, so rather than missing, I would say it doesn't have it, or doesn't force you to use it. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Symfony2, there's no such concept as ViewModel. Your pass into templates entities or models directly. Still, you can build your own ViewModel.

Entities aren't models. They are doctrine managed objects, or domain entities as you said. If you want to have business models, put them in MyBundle/Model as many other bundles do (for example, [FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/)).

Comment: Sounds good. But still i consider entities as models in many situations. Anyway thanks, i will as fosuserbundle does.

Comment: If you are talking about a domain model, then yes, an entity is an item within your domain model.

Comment: @wilmoore Yes unless you want to support two database types for your entity. You can add Doctrine ODM, where no entity exists but only documents. If you use models for domain model, all you need to do is to change the underlinying object that implements ORM-related stuff in your models.

Comment: It is just a bit of bad terminology on the part of Doctrine. All over their documentation for the ODM they talk about "Persistent Models"; however, in a solid architecture, "Model" is actually the collection of things that model your business. They refer to "Persistent Models", but a more accurate term would be "Persistent Entity". The example here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#persistent-models, talks about a "User", and given that a User is uniquely identified, it is an Entity regardless of where you Persist.

Comment: @wilmoore No, the terminology is good but the terms are very overloaded. "Persistence Model' is a set of objects that are mapped to the database. In Doctrine ORM they're also called entities, in ODM - documents. "Domain Model" is the collection of things that mapped to the business needs. They are separate concepts, but can be implemented in the same object.

Comment: @meze I agree that the terms are overloaded and that is why it is difficult to land on something we are both comfortable with. You are going based on Doctrine's terminology and that is good enough in most cases as to not get too pedantic about it :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter where you place your `ViewModel`... as long as your namespace reflects its location.

I would place it in `src/MyCompany/MyBundle/View/Model` and then your namespace would be `MyCompany\MyBundle\View\Model`.